# HTML5 pattern for input(mask)

Tags: javascript, html

```
( (0)|(\d{1,3})([\,])(\d{2}))
```

we would like get pattern for pattern `0` or number format `***,**` in input, where * is number.
But we cann't find options for this regexp .
How syntax will be right in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some example?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? (well, aside from the space at the beginning)

Comment: @RahulTripathi `<input type="text" name="cost" required pattern="( (0)|(\d{1,3})([\,])(\d{2}))">`

Comment: @SecondRikudo we are get error `enter the data in the specified format`

Comment: the code you posted here...run it in fiddle.its working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space at the beginning is what's causing you trouble.

```html
<form action="foo.html">
    <input type="text" required pattern="((0)|(\d{1,3})([\,])(\d{2}))" />
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```